# Passing user state to child component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a parent component which gets the users state (either logged in or not) and should be able to pass this state to the child component and display a link based on whether or not they're logged in. However, I'm having trouble passing the `loggedIn` state down to the child component, so it can be used to show or hide the link based on the users state:

**Parent component**

```
class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    if (this.md.mobile()) {
      this.setState({ blocking: 'mobile' })
    } else if (this.browser.name === 'ie' || this.browser.name === 'edge') {
      this.setState({ blocking: 'unsupported' })
    } else {
      try {
        const userData = await superagent.get('/api/user')

        if (!userData.error) {
          this.setState({ user: userData.body })
        }
        const loggedIn = userData.body.success <==RETURNS FALSE IF USER IS LOGGED OUT AND "UNDEFINED" IF USER IS LOGGED IN
        console.log(loggedIn)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Could not fetch user.', err)
      }

      this.fetchData()
    }
  }

  /**
   * render
   */

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='video-player-container'>
        { this.state.blocking === 'paywall' &&
          <Paywall
            bgImgUrl={this.props.imageUrl('paywall-bg.png' )}
            logoUrl={this.props.imageUrl('logo.png')}
            loggedIn={!!this.state.user && this.state.user.success === undefined}
            {...this.props}
          />
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
function Paywall (props) {
  const { iconHrefs, logoUrl, bgImgUrl, config } = props

  return (
    <div
      className='blocking-paywall'
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImgUrl})` }}>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={logoUrl} />
        </div>

        <h1 className='heading lg'>{content.heading}</h1>

        <div className='message'>
          <div className='subpara'>
            content
          </div>
          <div className='subpara'>
            catchphrase
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='login'>
          { !props.loggedIn &&  <==SHOULD ONLY SHOW LOGIN LINK IF USER IS NOT LOGGED IN
            <p>already a member?<a href='/login'>Login</a></p>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your are not passing `loggedIn` property to your child component

```
<Paywall
        bgImgUrl={this.props.imageUrl('paywall-bg.png' )}
        logoUrl={this.props.imageUrl('logo.png')}
        {/* How did you expect child component to get loggedIn?*/}
        loggedIn={!!this.state.user && this.state.user.success === undefined}
        {...this.props} 
      />
```

Then your `Paywall` is **stateless** component. It has no instance, you can't use `this` in render method

```
  <div className='login'>
      { !props.loggedIn &&  <==SHOULD ONLY SHOW LOGIN LINK IF USER IS NOT LOGGED IN
        <p>already a member?<a href='/login'>Login</a></p>
      }
    </div>
```

Comment: I've updated my code based on your suggestion, but the link still shows when the user is logged in.

Comment: @Matt Since you are using undefined as flag `this.state.user.success === undefined` Or `"UNDEFINED"`? :) Who knows :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass loggedIn as a prop to paywall, as you don't get it as a prop on parent component, so {...this.props} is not enough.